# How to prevent pinch gesture in MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, multi-touch

As `MPMoviePlayerViewController` supports pinch gesture ( two fingers move apart ) to make the movie player full screen, is there any method to remove this gesture? Because if I use the gesture, the movie is still playing without the video. I think the view of movie controller is removed from super view.

I tried overriding `touchesBegan` and the notification `WillEnterFullScreenNotification` & `DidEnterFullScreenNotfication`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with the "pinch gesture" reorienting the video display from landscape to portrait. I solved it by accessing the view property of the `MPMoviePlayerController` object and setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`.

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[moviePlayer view].userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

This prevents any user touches from getting through and changing the orientation or fullscreen status of the `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Comment: This code disables also video controls. I've added working solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the accepted answer from jontron/curhipster didn't work.

But when I set the moviePlayers `controlStyle` to `MPMovieScalingModeFill` the pesky pinch was ignored.

My code:

```
NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tutorial" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayerController];

[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
self.moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
self.moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
[self.moviePlayerController play];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct solution

```
[[[self.moviePlayer view] subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
           [[view gestureRecognizers] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id pinch, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                if([pinch isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {
                    [view removeGestureRecognizer:pinch];
                }
           }];
      }];
```